# Why isn't my SwiftUI List's background image centered properly?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, alignment

I'm trying to fill the background of a List with an `Image` which should be cut off at screen borders with `scaledToFill` such that the image's center ends up in the middle of the screen. When running the code below, I get an incorrectly centered, yet correctly cropped background image. This only happens when running in portrait mode but not in landscape. (The image is in 16:9 landscape and needs to fill the screen)

Why is this happening and why only in portrait mode?

---

View extension:

```swift
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func fullBackground(uiImage image: UIImage?) -> some View {
        background {
            if image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List View:

```
List {
    /* ... */
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.fullBackground(uiImage: myImage)
```

[Screenshot (red line is image center)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmx2q.jpg)

---

I've tried adding `frame(alignment: .center)` to the Image or using `background(alignment: .center)` but neither changed anything.

I also attempted placing the `Image` behind the other views with a `ZStack` but this broke the list as all the items' `Label`s disappeared and the list style was reset.

(Tested on iPhone 14 Pro Simulator with iOS 17.0 and real iPhone SE (2nd gen.) with iOS 16.6; Xcode 15.0 beta 5)

Comment: If it is scaled to fill, in portrait, it needs to become much wider than the window in order to fit the height. Maybe you want `scaledToFit`?

Comment: It should work in portrait or landscape mode, and always needs to fill the screen. If I set it to scaledToFit, it doesn't fill the screen and gets black borders instead.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you don't want to use either `scaledToFit` or `scaledToFill` because they both keep the original aspect ratio. Instead, you could just set an infinite frame on it and it will fill its parent size.

Comment: I thought `scaledToFit` fills the parent view by scaling the image up just enough, doesn't it? The scaling is correct, it's just not centered correctly.

Comment: `scaledToFit` will scale the image up so that each dimension is filled. It does not change the center point based on that scaling. If you want to change the center point, you'd need to do that manually, but `scaledToFit` doesn't tell you _how much_ it was scaled by.

Comment: As far as I know, the image's center point should be in the middle of the screen, regardless of its scaling mode. I assumed that the image would be centered automatically and the question is why it isn't. (Hope this helps to understand the question)

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the problem.